# How could I show the edges of a network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I used networkx to establish a network, and I want to draw it, but the edges between the nodes could not be displayed. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
network=nx.DiGraph()
datacal=pd.read_excel('D:/20110630.xlsx',index_col=0)
for i in range(len(datacal)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(datacal)):
        if datacal.iloc[i][j]!=0:
             network.add_edge(datacal.index[i],datacal.columns[j])
nx.draw_networkx(network,node_size=15)
plt.show()
```

This is my picture:
[image]

I can only plot the nodes of the network.

Answer (score 1):

Have you played around with width and edge_color? Maybe you simply can not see the edges in the plot because you have many nodes...
Oh and try to verify whether your are appending the edges correctly (e.g. with G.edges())

Try this out:

```
nx.draw_networkx(network,node_size=15, edge_color="k", width=10)
```